# How to prove that $\int_{\partial A}\frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert^n}\cdot \nu(x)d\sigma = \int_{\partial B_1(0)}1d\sigma$?

Tags: integration, differential-geometry

I am having some difficulty finding a proof idea for this question I found in an old exam:

Suppose $A\subset\mathbb R^n$ is a bounded $C^1$ set with outer unit normal $\nu_A(x)$ and $0\in A$. Prove that $$\int_{\partial A}\frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert^n}\cdot \nu_A(x)d\sigma = \int_{\partial B_1(0)}1d\sigma.$$
**Hint**: Consider the set $A_\epsilon:=A\setminus B_\epsilon(0)$ for sufficiently small $\epsilon$.

Comment: Hint: Use multi-dimensional integration by parts on $A_{\varepsilon}$ and then, apply change of variables to change the domain of integration to some domain $B_{1}^{\varepsilon}(0)\subseteq B_1(0)$.

Comment: I didn't write that you could change it to $B_1(0)$. I said some sub-domain of $B_1(0)$. I even denoted it $B_1^{\varepsilon}(0)$.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Apply the divergence theorem on $A_\epsilon$. Have you written that out?

Comment: P.S. You should also note that $A\subset\Bbb R^n$ is a compact $n$-dimensional submanifold with boundary. Dimensions matter.

Comment: The divergence theorem once again tells you the integral is independent of $\epsilon$, but you can see it explicitly by parametrizing the sphere of radius $\epsilon$ by the sphere of radius $1$. How are the $d\sigma$’s related?

Comment: @TedShifrin I just found the general relationship of $r$ and an $n$-spheres surface area! The more you know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @TedShifrin

Following the hint and comment recommendations, consider $A_\epsilon\subset A$ and note that $B_\epsilon(0)\subset A$ for sufficiently small $\epsilon$, using the quotient rule
$$\begin{aligned}\int_{A_\epsilon}\text{div} \frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert^n}dx 
&= \int_{A_\epsilon}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial_i}{\partial x_i} \frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert^n}dx\\
&= \int_{A_\epsilon}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\lVert x\rVert^n - x_in\lVert x\rVert^{n-1}x_i\lVert x\rVert^{-1}}{\lVert x\rVert^{2n}}dx\\
&= \int_{A_\epsilon}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\lVert x\rVert ^2 - x_i^2 n}{\lVert x\rVert^{n+2}}dx\\
&=n\int_{A_\epsilon}\frac 1 {\lVert x\rVert^n}(1 -\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i^2}{\lVert x\rVert^{2}})dx\\
&= 0.
\end{aligned}$$

So by the divergence theorem, keeping in mind the orientation of the outer normals, we have
$$0 = \int_{\partial A} \frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert^n}\cdot \nu_A(x)d\sigma - \int_{\partial B_\epsilon(0)}\frac{x}{\epsilon^n}\cdot \frac x {\epsilon}d\sigma.$$
Taking a closer look at the second term,
$$\int_{\partial B_\epsilon(0)}\frac{x}{\epsilon^n}\cdot \frac x {\epsilon}d\sigma = \int_{\partial B_\epsilon(0)}\frac{\lVert x\rVert^2}{\epsilon^{n+1}}d\sigma = \int_{\partial B_\epsilon(0)}\frac{1}{\epsilon^{n-1}}d\sigma = \int_{\partial B_1(0)}1d\sigma$$